# Item Template for Dynamic DataList

Tags: asp.net, datalist

i have Dynamic  Datalist using code:-

```
         DataList dl = new DataList();
        dl.DataSource = settings.GetUsers();
        form1.Controls.Add(dl);
```

but its not working how can i set item template or another template for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the templates programmaticly, look at [Creating Web Server Control Templates Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289501%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?ppud=4).

Your create a class that has to inherit `ITemplate`, and then you can assign it to a template property on a listview/datalist/repeater/etc. `ITemplate` will require you to have the following method:

```
public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container) {
}
```

This method allows you to build the control tree you want to create as template.